# Synchronizing MySql Server and VB.Net Winform Application

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Good day good sirs.

I have a winform application and a Mysql server for the database. In my application, I have several date fields wherein it displays dates of transactions like start date and time. In the application, it is set to follow the date and time of the computer (client) and not the server and when I change the client date and time, it saves as it is and not the server time which compromises data integrity and accuracy. How can i set the client machine to follow the server date and time. Is there any way or techniques to avoid these problem. Like how can i set the appliocation to check if the server and client has thesame date before starting the application. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inserting your records in the MySQL database you can use the NOW() function for the datetime field instead of passing in the current datetime from the client machine. NOW() will evaluate on the server and therefore be the server datetime.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_now.asp

Comment: How about when comparing dates. Like when the user input a start date and compare it on the database date. how can i address the issue?

Comment: You can use a query "select NOW()" to get the time from the server and then compare it in the client application and make any adjustments you need to. Things would be a little more complex if your clients are in different time zones. In that case you may want to convert to a common time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using an EPOCH timestamp?
[Unix Time Stamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php)

Carrying this value instead of datetime values would provide a common base from which to determine the local (client) datetime values.